# What are the differences between visual studio and VS express edition?

Tags: visual-studio

What are the differences between visual studio and VS express edition?

Probably very googelable, but than again, I have read that coverage in StackOverflow is a good thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [download a comparison](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/9/0/590E8F3D-77B1-4C5A-9FA7-0C526409836F/VisualStudio2008_Comparative.xls) from Microsoft. And another one from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=727bcfb0-b575-47ab-9fd8-4ee067bb3a37).

Answer (score 1):

The Express edition does not come with the Microsoft C++ runtime redistributable packages, nor does it itself grant you permission to distribute them. So the users of the software you build with the Express edition will have to download & run the installers themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I might have missed it in the excel sheet, but some big ones are lack of proper source control integration and 3rd party tool integrations.  Express editions are missing unit tests as wel.

Answer (score 0):

Lack of support in Refactoring and advanced debugging is a major issue I feel.